# Why this 2nd circle didn't show?

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect, uibezierpath

if i Commented the shapeShadow code,it will show the 2nd circle.
what happened in     `-(void)shapeShadow:(UIBezierPath *)shape` ?

-(void)shapeShadow:(UIBezierPath *)shape This code is add line in circle.

```
#import "SetCard.h"

@implementation SetCard
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath *roundedRect=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:10];
    [roundedRect addClip];
    [[UIColor whiteColor]setFill];
    UIRectFill(self.bounds);
    [[UIColor blackColor]setStroke];
    [self drawShape];
}
-(void)drawShape
{
    CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    for (int i=1; i<3; i++) {
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, self.bounds.size.width*(i-1)/3, 0);
        [self drawCircle];
    }
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
-(UIBezierPath  *)drawCircle
{
    CGPoint center=CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.height/5, self.bounds.size.height/2);
    UIBezierPath *circle=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:self.bounds.size.height/5 startAngle:0 endAngle:12 clockwise:YES];
    [circle closePath];
    circle.lineWidth=3;
    [[UIColor blueColor]setFill];
    [[UIColor blackColor]setStroke];
    [circle stroke];      [self shapeShadow:circle];

    return circle;
}
-(void)shapeShadow:(UIBezierPath *)shape
{
//    [shape addClip];
//    for(int j=0;j<15;j++){
//        CGFloat c=0.05*j*self.bounds.size.height;
//        UIBezierPath *line=[UIBezierPath bezierPath];
//        [line moveToPoint:CGPointMake(c, 0.0)];
//        [line addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(c, self.bounds.size.height)];
//        line.lineWidth=2;
//        [line fill];[line stroke];
//    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that method calls `[shape addClip]` and that converts the path into a clipping specification so it no longer draws, it prevents drawing in a specified area.